# .NET Core 2.1 app fails in Azure but works elsewhere

Tags: .net, azure, asp.net-core, .net-core

My .NET Core 2.1 web app works fails to start on Azure App Service.  It works fine in IIS Express locally or on a Raspberry Pi.

The errors `return type must be 'Task' to match overridden member` and `Reference to type 'Task' claims it is defined in 'System.Runtime', but it could not be found` - I haven't seen them before.  Sounds like some type of version mismatch, but upon review everything seems legit and, like I said, it works fine when deployed to Linux/RaspberryPi.  `Views_Home_Landing` refers to my default action on the controller.

I've tried deploying self-contained and framework-dependent, but the error is always the same.

Running `dotnet --list-runtimes` returns Microsoft.NETCore.App 2.1.5 and Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 2.1.5 (latest).  Running `dotnet --list-sdks` returns 2.1.403

What am I missing?

P.S. While I didn't find a solution, I deleted the app from Azure and deployed it as a new app and it all worked fine.

```
fail: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.ExceptionHandlerMiddleware[1]
  An unhandled exception has occurred while executing the request.
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.Compilation.CompilationFailedException: One or more compilation failures occurred:
mkitun4v.pui(70,67): error CS0508: 'Views_Home_Landing.ExecuteAsync()': return type must be 'Task' to match overridden member 'RazorPageBase.ExecuteAsync()'
mkitun4v.pui(70,67): error CS7069: Reference to type 'Task' claims it is defined in 'System.Runtime', but it could not be found
mkitun4v.pui(75,13): error CS7069: Reference to type 'Task' claims it is defined in 'System.Runtime', but it could not be found
mkitun4v.pui(75,37): error CS7069: Reference to type 'Task' claims it is defined in 'System.Runtime', but it could not be found
mkitun4v.pui(187,43): error CS7069: Reference to type 'Task' claims it is defined in 'System.Runtime', but it could not be found
mkitun4v.pui(332,19): error CS7069: Reference to type 'Task' claims it is defined in 'System.Runtime', but it could not be found
mkitun4v.pui(335,23): error CS7069: Reference to type 'Task' claims it is defined in 'System.Runtime', but it could not be found
mkitun4v.pui(343,13): error CS7069: Reference to type 'Task' claims it is defined in 'System.Runtime', but it could not be found
mkitun4v.pui(343,45): error CS7069: Reference to type 'Task' claims it is defined in 'System.Runtime', but it could not be found
mkitun4v.pui(362,13): error CS7069: Reference to type 'Task' claims it is defined in 'System.Runtime', but it could not be found
mkitun4v.pui(362,38): error CS7069: Reference to type 'Task' claims it is defined in 'System.Runtime', but it could not be found
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.Internal.RazorViewCompiler.CompileAndEmit(RazorCodeDocument codeDocument, String generatedCode)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.Internal.RazorViewCompiler.CompileAndEmit(String relativePath)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.Internal.RazorViewCompiler.OnCacheMiss(String normalizedPath)
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.Internal.DefaultRazorPageFactoryProvider.CreateFactory(String relativePath)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.RazorViewEngine.CreateCacheResult(HashSet`1 expirationTokens, String relativePath, Boolean isMainPage)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.RazorViewEngine.OnCacheMiss(ViewLocationExpanderContext expanderContext, ViewLocationCacheKey cacheKey)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.RazorViewEngine.LocatePageFromViewLocations(ActionContext actionContext, String pageName, Boolean isMainPage)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.RazorViewEngine.FindView(ActionContext context, String viewName, Boolean isMainPage)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewEngines.CompositeViewEngine.FindView(ActionContext context, String viewName, Boolean isMainPage)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures.ViewResultExecutor.FindView(ActionContext actionContext, ViewResult viewResult)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures.ViewResultExecutor.ExecuteAsync(ActionContext context, ViewResult result)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewResult.ExecuteResultAsync(ActionContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker.InvokeResultAsync(IActionResult result)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker.InvokeNextResultFilterAsync[TFilter,TFilterAsync]()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker.Rethrow(ResultExecutedContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker.ResultNext[TFilter,TFilterAsync](State& next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker.InvokeResultFilters()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker.InvokeNextResourceFilter()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker.Rethrow(ResourceExecutedContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker.Next(State& next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker.InvokeFilterPipelineAsync()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker.InvokeAsync()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder.RouterMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext httpContext)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles.StaticFileMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.ExceptionHandlerMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
```

Comment: Azure App Service or Azure Virtual Machine? Don't ask others to guess.

Comment: @LexLi Azure App Service.  Question updated.

Comment: Do you have any warnings in Visual Studio related to mismatches of that particular DLL, or multiple versions, or something to that effect? Is your reference defined in `packages.config` or `appsettings.json`?

Comment: @nightblade9 I do not have a `packages.config`.  And `appsettings.json` is just settings.  System.Runtime comes as part of the .NET Core 2.1 SDK and it is referenced in the project.

Comment: @AngryHacker my (admittedly limited) understanding of .NET core is that *everything* is a NuGet package. See [this System.Runtime package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Runtime/) on NuGet.org.  I know Visual Studio sometimes hides this detail from us.